# How to integrate YAF in N2-based ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, forum, n2, yaf

I'm building an N2-based ASP.NET MVC site, which is part of a larger Windows Azure solution. The problem I am stuck with is integrating in my project N2's own [forum add-on](http://n2cms.com/add-ons/Forum-v1.0.1.aspx), which is basically YAF (Yet Another Forum).

I've been wrestling with the forum for the last couple of days and after re-compiling the add-on to remove the dependency on *N2.Templates.dll* and following all of the steps in the *Installation.txt* file (part of the documentation of the add-on) I'm stuck with the forum not showing up. When I navigate to the forum I get a **"403.14 - Forbidden"** error.

From what I could find out it seems the problem is in the fact that the forum is based on WebForms and the containing application is MVC-based. The site is part of a Windows Azure solution and some of the things I read suggest the local IIS may not be correctly configured. However, right-clicking on the Forum.aspx page and selecting "View in browser" shows the page just fine, including navigating to subsequent pages from the YAF installation wizard. Running pure WebForms apps on the local IIS also goes without problems, so I think IIS is not the cause for YAF not showing up.

Please, if someone has any idea for solving this problem, or has done similar integration of YAF in an MVC site, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Since I'm a new user, I can only have one URL in my post. Here are some more:
N2 CMS - http://n2cms.com/
YAF - http://www.yetanotherforum.net/

Comment: You can have multiple links in your question. Take a look at the markdown you can use on these forums: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried what's mentioned in the page you posted, but all I get when I have more than one URL is an error message that says new users with less than 10 reputation points are allowed to post one URL only.